# Is there a way to change the diff color highlight in visual code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

In visual code when using side-by-side comparison you can see the differences, when added the line is green, but if the change is only a word or some part of the line that section will be highlighted.
I want to put more contrast or change only that highlight color.

I have tried changing in theme color customization the property: "diffEditor.insertedTextBackground" but the specific highlight color changes with the background.

Here is a image about the highlight:

[Color highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fvIp.png)